# In MVC3, what is the difference between the "JavaScript" and "Content" functions?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

In ASP.NET MVC3, the following two methods *seem* to return the same results:

```
public ActionResult Blah()
{
    return JavaScript("alert('" + DateTime.Now + "');");
}

public ActionResult Blah()
{
    return Content("alert('" + DateTime.Now + "');");
}
```

But, when I view the results of the first one in Google Chrome, the font is a Mono-Spaced font, whereas the second is Arial (or something).

This leads me to believe that there is probably a header "content-type" of "text/javascript" or something coming across the wire...

My question then is this:

- What does the "JavaScript" function (which yields a JavaScriptResult) do **that the Content method (which yields a ContentResult) does not do?**
- What are the benefits to this method?

**Please, do not include religious reasons as to why this method is "bad"... I'm only concerned with knowing the "what"... as in "what does it do?"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript actionresult sets the response.ContentType to application/x-javascript
where as the content actionresult can be set by calling its ContentType property.

JavascriptResult:

```
using System;
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public class JavaScriptResult : ActionResult
    {
        public string Script
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
            if (this.Script != null)
            {
                response.Write(this.Script);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContentResult

```
public class ContentResult : ActionResult
{
    public string Content
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Encoding ContentEncoding
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ContentType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
        }
        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (this.Content != null)
        {
            response.Write(this.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

The benefits are you are being explicit in your MVC code that this is JS and that you result is being sent to the client with the correct ContentType.

Comment: Can you include an actual benefit ... such as "browser 'xyz' will not execute JavaScript unless you include this content header" or something?

Comment: That is the benefit. A client can make decisions based on the response metadata.